# Prove that a 3x3 matrix always has an eigenvector in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove this statement. I am assuming that if a 3x3 matrix always has an eigenvector, then it also always has an eigenvalue. I tried to prove this looking at a general 3x3 case and trying to calculate det(A-$\lambda$I)=0, but it does not get me anywhere. Is there something intuitive that I am missing?

Comment: This is not the same question as the linked one. Please read more carefully before markiing a question as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

The characteristic polynomial is a cubic polynomial. Every cubic polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root. Hence every real $3\times 3$ matrix has at least one real eigenvalue, and obviously, a corresponding eigenvector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: @amsmath -- Read the title again

Comment: You too. The eigenvector is supposed to be real. Plus: You edited the answer after I commented. So, you did what I told you to do. Good.

Comment: @amsmath -- Sorry, I don't understand your comments. Are you a machine? Please prove that you are not.

Comment: That's a pitty. Since it's so easy to understand it.

Comment: Ok, just for you. You proved that $A$ has a real eigenvalue. Now prove that it has a corresponding eigenvector with real entries.

Comment: omg. We are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Right? (read the question). The definition of the concept "eigenvalue" involves the concept of an eigenvector, right? So what is it you want from me, dude?

Comment: Ok, I give it up. @briiibriiiii If $Ax = \lambda x$ with $x\in\mathbb C^3$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, then consider the vector $\overline x$, where $\overline x$ has the complex conjugates of $x$ as entries. Since $A$ has only real entries, $A\overline x = \overline{Ax} = \overline{\lambda x} = \lambda\overline x$. So, $A(x+\overline x) = Ax + A\overline x = \lambda x + \lambda\overline x = \lambda(x+\overline x)$. Hence $x+\overline x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @amsmath You don't need to prove that. There is a general theorem: if $A$ is a matrix in $M_n(F)$ (when $F$ is a field) then a scalar $\lambda\in F$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if it is a root of the characteristic polynomial. By $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue I mean it is an eigenvalue in in the field $F$, which by definition means that it has an eigenvector in $F^3$. You don't need the field to be algebraically closed or something.

Comment: @Mark I know that. But this is missing in the answer. And since it is explicitly asked for a real eigenvector, one has to say at least something about it. Especially because OP seems to be a little confused about eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: @amsmath Ok, maybe uniquesolution should have written in the beginning of the answer that we are working only in the field $\mathbb{R}$-the matrix has entries in that field, we find the characteristic polynomial over that field and we get that it has a root in that field. This is all what we need. So we act like we never heard about complex numbers.

Comment: @Mark Yes, for example.